# OpenSearch on AWS does not recognise GeoIP's location as GEOJSON type

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, geoip, opensearch

I've got logstash processing logs and uploading to an opensearch instance running on AWS as a service.

I've added a geoip filter to my logstash to process IPs into geographic data. According to the docs, the geoip filter should generate a `location` field that contains `lon` and `lat` and that should be recognised as a `geo_point` type which can then be used to populate map visualisations.

I've been trying for a couple of hours now but opensearch always splits the `location` field into the numbers `location.lon` and `location.lat` instead of just recognising `location` as `geo_point`, hence I cannot use it for map visualisations.

Here is my logstash config:

```
input {
    file {

        ...

        codec => json {
            target => "[log_message]"
        }
  }
}

filter {

    ...

    geoip {
        source => "[log_message][forwarded_ip_address]"
    }
}

output {

  ...

  opensearch {

        ...

        ecs_compatibility => disabled
  }
}
```

The template on my opensearch instance is the standard one, so it does contain this:

```
"geoip": {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties": {
            "ip": {
              "type": "ip"
            },
            "latitude": {
              "type": "half_float"
            },
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "longitude": {
              "type": "half_float"
            }
          }
        },
```

I am not sure if this is relevant but AWS OpenSearch requires the ECS compatibility to be set as `disabled`, which I did.

Has somebody managed to do this successfully on AWS OpenSearch?

Comment: Yeah this is lame, did you ever figure out how to create geo_point field types?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the location field as geo_point type in the index before ingesting the data? I don't think opensearch detects the geo_point type automatically.